# ArcCatalog metadata XML importing errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, metadata, xml, arccatalog

I am trying to add metadata to some layers within ArcCatalog and I don't understand the error messages it is giving me or why there would be an error. When I try to import my metadata XML it completes the process successfully. However some of the fields and aliases are mixed up.

**An example of the error messages I'm receiving:**

```
[ERROR] - ESRITranslator - Required variable is not bound to any value: CodeList: container[_GEN0] fragment[code] clause:  ChooseNode:20754675
```

or

```
[ERROR] - ESRITranslator - Error [InvalidForOne]: fragment[EnumeratedDomain] clause:  for-one clause: em:source (v:Subject, v:String) <edomvds>
```

**An example of what I mean when I say the field names and aliases are getting mixed up:**
[image]

*The mix ups of field names and aliases are not consistent either. Sometimes the only thing wrong is the field name, sometimes the alias is the only thing wrong.

What can I do to fix this?